# Rails - Generate CSV with comma as decimal separator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

In a `rails 5.2.0` and `ruby 2.5.1` project I'm generating CSV files where there are a lot of decimal numbers, formatting them with `number_to_rounded` and using comma as decimal separator:

```
irb(main):006:0> number_to_rounded(tot_calculation, precision: 2, separator: ',')
=> "0,37"



irb(main):214:0> rows << [ number_to_rounded(p.import, precision: 2, separator: ','), number_to_rounded(p.last_value, precision: 2, separator: ','),number_to_rounded(p.percentage, precision: 2, separator: ',')]
=> [["110000,00", "110000,00", "0,46"]]
```

When exporting csv with

```
csv_data = CSV.generate(headers: true, col_sep: ';') do |csv|
  csv << headers
  rows.each { |row| csv << row }
end
data_csv.attach(io: StringIO.new(csv_data), filename: "#{Date.today.strftime("%Y%m%d")}_daily.csv", content_type: 'text/csv')
```

decimal separator used is dot instead of comma. I checked locale and it is `:it` as it should be.

csv_data is: `".......on\n110000,00;110000,00;0,46\n"`

The plaintext of generated file is using dots: `0.00;943.84;943.84;90.00;100.00;117000.00;117000.00;`

[image: Decimals separated by dot]

How can I make generated CSV using comma as decimal separator?

Comment: CSV means that whole values get separated by commas - E.g. 0.00, 943.84
The fact that individual values contain dots instead of commas like in 943.84 has to do with the locale that you are using in your env. Try changing the system locale and how numbers are displayed for that matter and check if it alters the value representations.

Comment: Locale is right, `:it` in this case.

Comment: Please paste the raw generated CSV output (the actual text), because I see that the values are in tabular format, which means that you have opened it with some 3rd party app. It happens that if you open a CSV with Excel for instance, it applies its own formatting on the values.

Comment: You have to add the _formatted_ values, e.g. `csv << ['0,00', '943,84']`. Of course, you can use `number_to_rounded` to format them.

Comment: edit on the post

Comment: Did you check the CSV file in a plain text editor? Maybe the program you use to view the CSV file converts the decimal commas back to decimal points. Your screenshot looks like a spreadsheet application.

Comment: @Stefan yep, it is using dot

Comment: What is the content of your `csv_data` variable right after the `CSV.generate` invocation?

Comment: @Stefan `.......on\n110000,00;110000,00;0,46\n"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244869/discussion-between-stefan-and-joe).

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about commas, you just have to pass the *formatted* values as strings, e.g.:

```
csv_data = CSV.generate(col_sep: ';') do |csv|
  csv << ['1,95', '14,50']
  csv << ['2,75', '18,99']
end

File.write('test.csv', csv_data)
```

Content of `test.csv`:

```
1,95;14,50
2,75;18,99
```

Note that the values are not getting modified this way, i.e. commas and trailing zeros are retained.

You can of course use `number_to_rounded` to generate the formatted string values.